# Load custom css after bootstrap

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style, twitter-bootstrap, wp-register-style

I have this in functions.php. How can I modify it so that my custom css is loaded after bootsrap.min.css?

```
function register_css() {
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_css' );
```

I found [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-wp_enqueue-twitter-bootstrap-css-before-stylescss-is-loaded?replies=3) but it doesn't work and I don't know much about php but I think it's missing the wp_register_style part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above looks correct, however, you need to specify your script to enqueue after bootstrap by adding the `bootstrap-min` handle to the third, dependencies parameter.

```
function register_css() {
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'custom-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.min.css', 'bootstrap-min' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-min' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_css' );
```

See [wp_register_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) for more.

Alternatively you can, if you know you need to enqueue the files immediately from within your callback function, use `wp_enqueue_style` just like `wp_register_style`, see: [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)